# Configurable Timer Triggers - Azure Web Jobs

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, webjob

I'm building a job to trigger at some regular interval (say 1 minute). I've successfully used triggered web jobs with time-span hard coded in the functions.

```
public void foo([TimerTrigger("00:01:00")] TimerInfo timer)
```

Now if I ever want to change the trigger time from 1-min to 2-min I've to redeploy the code. Instead is there a way to make the TimeTrigger Configurable, from a config file.

Note that replacing the string with a dynamically read value isn't possible as the TimerTrigger Attribute is a const string expression or a Type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After much digging, I've realized that this can be done with an SDK extension class `TimerSchedule`.

For it, you would need a base class that you'll be able to use for multiple triggers.

```
class CustomTimerTriggerBase: TimerSchedule
{
    TimeSpan timer;
    public CustomTimerTriggerBase(string triggerConfigKey)
    {
        timer=TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[triggerConfigKey]);
    }

    public override DateTime GetNextOccurrence(DateTime now)
    {
        return now.Add(timer);
    }
}
```

Use this Base to generate your timers...

```
public sealed class FooTimer : CustomTimerTriggerBase
{
    public FooTimer() : base("FooTimerKey") {}
}
```

In your, App.config have a key for "FooTimer"

```
<add key="FooTimerKey" value="00:02:00" />
```

Use this FooTimer class in your webjob functions.

```
public void foo([TimerTrigger(typeof(FooTimer)] TimerInfo timer)
```

Now you can simply change the value in app config instead of redeploying the code. 
**NOTE**: Since you are using Timespan to parse, the string can be of any format you need as defined in TimeSpan formats.

---

**UPDATE**

As pointed by [l--''''''---------''''''''''''](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117700/l) and [Andy Dobedoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9032853/andy-dobedoe)
 now (as of 2019) it is much simpler to achieve this.

`public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%MYCRON%")]TimerInfo myTimer`

Finds the setting called MYCRON and uses the cron expression from there

Comment: This no longer works.  If you put a `FunctionName` attribute on a function (needed for it to work) and a `TimerTrigger` that takes a `type` rather than a cron expression, it fails to compile with "System.NotImplementedException: Property 'ScheduleType' on attribute 'TimerTriggerAttribute' is not supported in Azure Functions."

Comment: the %MYCRON% expression did not work for me. but the other solution of extending TimerSchedule gave me the correct direction and with the help of below article I was able to achieve my objective of configurable cron expression in web job

https://matt.kotsenas.com/posts/combining-cronschedules-in-webjobs

Answer (score 10):

You can do this like so:

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%MYSCHEDULE%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
```

where `MYSCHEDULE` is an environment variable which you can store in your `local.settings.json` file as well as in your application settings in the portal.

An example value for `MYSCHEDULE` would be:

```
"MYSCHEDULE": "0 */2 * * * *"
```

Answer (score 8):

It turns out, this is pretty easy nowadays.  Just put the app setting in as your cron schedule expression and it will look it up for you.

e.g.

```
public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%MYCRON%")]TimerInfo myTimer
```

Finds the setting called MYCRON and uses the cron expression from there

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you need to specific the `scheduleExpression` parameter for `TimerTrigger` in your code or implement your `WeeklySchedule` or `DailySchedule` described in this sample [TimerSamples.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/ExtensionsSample/Samples/TimerSamples.cs). For changing the schedule without re-deploy your code, I assume that you could leverage [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-get-started-portal) to trigger your webjob on some schedule and you could change the schedule settings as you expected without re-deploy your webjob. For more details, you could refer to the section about adding a scheduler job in this [tutorial](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for a more configurable way, instead of just weekly or daily scheduling. I figured a way to do it with the inbuilt Azure SDK's `TimerSchedule` extension. It's basically the same as `WeeklyScedule` and `DailySchedule`, with more control.