# How to use a custom timer for Azure functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Apparently there used to be a way to create custom timers for Azure Functions, by creating a class that inherits from `TimerSchedule` and defining the custom logic in its `GetNextOccurrence` method.

We've got [an MSDN post about it,](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitagarwal/2018/01/01/custom-schedule-for-azure-web-job-timer-triggers/), we've got [a StackOverflow answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46398084/32914), and even [some official sample code that uses custom timers.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/ExtensionsSample/Samples/TimerSamples.cs)

None of it works.

None of these samples have a `FunctionName` attribute on their functions, which is needed (in the current SDK version, at least; not sure how long this has been the case) to make the Azure Function job actually run.  And in the current SDK, any function that has both a `FunctionName` and a `TimerTrigger` that uses a custom timer type will fail to build with an error like this:

> System.NotImplementedException: Property 'ScheduleType' on attribute 'TimerTriggerAttribute' is not supported in Azure Functions.

Apparently this used to work, but it doesn't now, and I'm having a heck of a time finding any relevant information on what the correct way is to do it now.  Does anyone know what the new way is to set up a custom timer?

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with timers directly. Queues might be the right choice here: The previous run would have to create a message and send it to the queue. Make sure that the message becomes visible only after a specified time.

An alternative is to use Durable Functions, in particular an "eternal orchestration". Check out the example in the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations#periodic-work-example), where a job gets kicked off after a specified amount of time after the previous one has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Those are all in relation to web jobs - Azure Functions are not web jobs.

[Azure Webjobs vs Azure Functions : How to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610952/azure-webjobs-vs-azure-functions-how-to-choose)

That said Azure Functions do have similiar timer functionaility - it even uses web job Nuget packages.

[Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer)

> The following example shows a C# function that is executed each time
>   the minutes have a value divisible by five (eg if the function starts
>   at 18:57:00, the next performance will be at 19:00:00):
>
> ```
> [FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
> public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
> ```

Comment: This example is a cron expression. It's exactly what I'm trying to figure out how to not use, because the logic I need can't be expressed as a cron expression and requires a custom timer that can compute any arbitrary time.

Comment: @masonwheeler looked at using a `TimeSpan` instead? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a programatically-derived schedule that is not fixed because the amount of time before the next iteration runs depends on the results of previous iterations. Anything with a fixed value, whether it be a `TimeSpan` or a cron expression, will not work.

Comment: (And before you respond with any specific details about how serverless works that would make that difficult to get right, yes, I'm aware of all of that. I still need arbitrary, programmatic schedule generation.)